# Grials update fails on unique constraint

Tags: validation, grails, constraints, unique

I have a user domain in which I have a unique constraint on it's employee number

```
class User {

    Integer employeeNumber
    String employeeLogin
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
    String nickname
    Date birthday

    static mapping = {
        table 'user'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'employeeNumber', type: 'int'
        employeeNumber column: 'employee_number'
        version false
        sort 'lastName'
    }

    static constraints = {
        employeeNumber(blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true)
        employeeLogin(blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true)
        firstName(blank: false, nullable: false)
        middleName(blank: true, nullable: true)
        lastName(blank: false, nullable: false)
        nickname(blank: true, nullable: true)
        birthday(blank: true, nullable: true)
    }
}
```

and I am trying to update the user with

```
class UserController {

    ...

    def saveUser() {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        if (params.userId) { // handles user update for existing employeeNumber
            def user = User.findByEmployeeNumber(params.userId) // sent in hidden field name userId with value employeeNumber

            user.employeeNumber = Integer.parseInt(params.employeeNumber)
            user.employeeLogin = params.employeeLogin
            user.firstName = params.firstName
            user.middleName = params.middleName
            user.lastName = params.lastName
            user.nickname = params.nickname
            try {
                user.birthday = formatter.parse(params.birthday)
            } 
            catch (Exception ignore) {
                user.birthday = null
            }

            if (user.validate()) {
                user.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
                redirect(action:'profile', id:user.employeeNumber)
            } else {
                render(view:'editUser', model:[user:user])
            }
        } else {  // handles new user
            ... // this part works
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

but it is catching on `if (user.validate()) { ... }` due to the unique constraints on `employeeNumber` and `employeeLogin`.

When creating a new user I want the username and id to be unique, but upon update I'd obviously like to update an existing user, however this unique constraint is blocking me from doing so. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: hum its something wrong, you look for the user and find it and then you want to update its key. normal the system is not happy; why do you want to set employeeNumber and employeeLogin if you were able to find the user (thus those values exists in first place because you were able once to create it) - you should just remove those 2 lines from the block

Comment: Frederic, I'm going to go with your suggestion. This kind of turned into a "should we" question instead of "could we". I'll keep the validation so that new users have unique username and id's, but make it so that once they're created, those two fields cannot be modified. Thanks!

Comment: Frederic, I went with your suggestion, but I'm still having the same error. I completely removed `user.employeeNumber = Integer.parseInt(params.employeeNumber)` and `user.employeeLogin = params.employeeLogin` but the unique constraint is still getting thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have made the **employeeNumber** field as your primary key

For Hibernate/Grails, Primary Key is the identifier value for an object. It is something that will never change during the life of the object

During update you are trying to modify the identifier which is causing the issue.

You can definitely modify a unique field, so in your case you can modify the **employeeLogin**. But you can't modify the Primary Key.

Also **employeeNumber** is already a primary key so don't declare it as a unique key. This will remove the unique key error that you are facing.

Comment: So then how do I perform an update? Per Frederic's suggestion, I removed `user.employeeNumber = Integer.parseInt(params.employeeNumber)` and `user.employeeLogin = params.employeeLogin`, but the unique constraint is still getting thrown when it tries to validate

Comment: Removing the unique constraint from `employeeNumber` took away that constraint validation error, but `Property [employeeLogin] of class [class User] with value [pwillard] must be unique` still appears

Comment: Well that seems an issue with Grails. As a workaround, you can write your own custom unique validator for employeeLogin field and removing the default unique constraint.

Comment: Also, removing the unique constraint from employeeNumber allows users info to be overwritten by new users info, so that constraint is a must as well.

Comment: It seems Grails is not handling the unique constraints well in case of assigned Primary Key.  So if you are not building your application with a legacy db, I would say you should use the default  generated id field as PK.